ActiveMQ Artemis metrics plugin filter object names/addresses
In a k8s Artemis deployment I configured the metrics plugin for Artemis following this guide.
Now I'm looking for a way to filter only some object names or some addresses like can be done using the JMX exporter.

Use the enable-metrics address-setting as described in the documentation, e.g.:
<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="myAddress">
      <enable-metrics>false</enable-metrics>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>


Thanks, with the Artemis Operator the same thing can be achieved using brokerProperties configuration:

'addressesSettings.myAddress.enableMetrics=false'

